# How to get Count in Lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, count, group-by

I have three models (Applicant, Meeting, City) and I joined three of them. I want to get Count by grouping MeetingId in Applicant model. Here are my models and method I use for populating Dropdownlist in Controller. So, like the **"Expired"** property in the Controller,  how can I obtain the count for the MeetingId by grouping on **"TotalMeetingById"** property?

**Applicant Model:**

```
public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubmitDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }   
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }
}
```

**Meeting Model:**

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int MeetingID { get; set; }
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }
    public DateTime MeetingStartDate { get; set; }       
    public DateTime? MeetingEndDate { get; set; }
    public int? TotalParticipant { get; set; }
    public int? MeetingCityId { get; set; } 

    public int? ParticipantCityAId { get; set; }
    public int? ParticipantCityBId { get; set; }
}
```

**City Model:**

```
public class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
private void PopulateDropDownList()
{
    var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
        .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m, cA = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(z => z.cA.Select(cA => new { m = z.m, cA }))
        .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.ParticipantCityAId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m.m, m.cA, cB = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(w => w.cB.Select(cB => new { m = w.m, cA = w.cA, cB }))
        .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.ParticipantCityBId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m.m, m.cA, m.cB, cC = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(t => t.cC.Select(cC => new { m = t.m, cA = t.cA, cB = t.cB, cC }))
        .Select(
            m =>
                new
                {
                    CityID = m.cA.CityID,
                    CityName = m.cA.CityName,
                    MeetingDate = m.m.MeetingStartDate,
                    MeetingName = m.m.MeetingName,
                    NameofMeetingCityIdA = m.cA != null ? m.cA.CityName : null,
                    NameofMeetingCityIdB = m.cB != null ? m.cB.CityName : null,
                    NameofMeetingCityIdC = m.cC != null ? m.cC.CityName : null
                })
        .OrderBy(x => x.CityID)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(
            i => new
            {
                Value = i.CityID.ToString(),
                DisplayValue = string.Format("{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})", i.NameofMeetingCityIdA, i.MeetingDate),
                Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow,
                TotalMeetingById= ??? >>> I cannot get the total count for the related MeetingId at here
            }
        ).ToList();

    var selectItems = new List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>(meetingsQuery.Count);
    foreach (var record in meetingsQuery)
    {
        var item = new MyHelpers.MySelectItem
        {
            Text = record.DisplayValue,
            Value = record.Value
        };
        if (record.Expired)
        {
            item.Class = "disabled";
            item.Disabled = "disabled";
        }
        selectItems.Add(item);
    }
    ViewBag.MeetingData = selectItems;
}
```

Here are sample data for models:

**Applicant:**

```
 ApplicantID : 100
 SubmitDate : 01/11/2013
 Name : Christof
 Surname : Jahnsen 
 MeetingId : 1
```

**Meeting:**

```
 MeetingID : 1
 MeetingName : City Information Days
 MeetingStartDate : 01/01/2014       
 MeetingEndDate : 02/01/2014
 TotalParticipant : 2 (for example) 
 MeetingCityId : 500
 ParticipantCityAId : 501
 ParticipantCityBId : 502
```

**City:**

```
CityID : 500 / 501 / 502
CityName : London / Paris / NY
```

**Update -----------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Razor:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Applicant.MeetingId)
@Html.MyDropdownListFor(m => m.Applicant.MeetingId, ViewBag.MeetingData as List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>, "---- Select ----",
        new { name = "meetingId", id = "meetingId" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Applicant.MeetingId, null, new { @class = "ValidationErrors" })
```

**Controller:**

```
public ViewResult Add()
{
    PopulateDropDownList();

    ApplicantViewModel model = new ApplicantViewModel
    {
        Applicant = new Applicant(),
        Applicants = repository.Applicants,
        Lookups = repository.Lookups,
        Cities = repository.Cities
        .ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(ApplicantViewModel model)
{
    ApplicantViewModel viewModel;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Applicant.SubmitDate = DateTime.Now;
        repository.SaveApplicant(model.Applicant);
        PopulateDropDownList(model.Applicant);
        return View("Completed", ViewBag.ApplicantId = model.Applicant.ApplicantID);
    }
    else
    {
        // there is something wrong with the data values
        PopulateDropDownList();
        TempData["message"] = "Please try again.";
        viewModel = new ApplicantViewModel
        {
            Applicant = new Applicant(),
            Applicants = repository.Applicants,
            Lookups = repository.Lookups,
            Cities = repository.Cities
            .ToList()
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to follow your code if you used more meaningful names than "m", "cC", "cA" etc. Also, it would probably be simpler as a query expression.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But using a name for letter maybe makes it much more difficult to read. If it is possible, could you please change them as you want on VS and help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You think giving meaningful names to variables makes code *more* difficult to read? I don't have time to go through and try to work out what your code is meant to do - but you should do that yourself. And with a query expression, you'll find you have fewer names to work out in the first place.

Comment: can you provide sample input data?

Comment: @H.Johnson what is field `ParticipantCityAId` etc? its not in model

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Ok, you are right. But the problem is not be able to use Count property on TotalMeetingById=... line. So, I need to join three tables (I did properly) and get count of MeetingId property in Applicant model. Is it impossible? Or what do you seggest me i.e. retrieving View from database instead of 3 tables? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Grundy: ParticipantCityAId is not important. Assume that, I have an Applicant model having MeetingId and Meeting model connecting to Applicant model with MeetingID. I joined three model (Applicant, Meeting and City) and the only thing I need to join three tables (I did properly) and get count of MeetingId property in Applicant model. But there is not such a property on TotalMeetingById=... line. Is it impossible? Or what do you suggest me i.e. retrieving View from database instead of 3 tables? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: so use `groupby` extension [Queryable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.queryable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy: ParticipantCityAId and ParticipantCityBId are in Meeting Model. I added them to the code above. Could you please give answer by updating the code as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: I solved the with the help of a method. But the only problem is the Dropdownlist cannot remember the selected value after postback. Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: @H.Johnson can you provide how you bind this list in html, and action on postback?

Comment: @Grundy: I added the related code at the end of my question. The strange thing that makes me confused why do I have to re-populate the related Dropdownlist even after postback while I do not populate never the other Dropdownlists that are bounded directly from the model. Spceial thanks for your determination to solve the problem. Kindest regards...

Comment: @Grundy: Any reply regarding to this issue please?

Comment: @H.Johnson you need populate dropdownlist on postback because mvc don't save state between request, so if you create your list dynamicaly you need populate it on every submit, also after populate you lose selection so you need manual set selected for item what you need. On postback in form data you can get item that selected now.

Comment: also you don't populate lists that are bounded directly from model because you pass model in view directly, in this case viewbag is empty on every request so you need fill it

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and very nice explanations. I will keep in all of your suggestions. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem with the help of using an external method out of Lambda expression.

```
private void PopulateMeetingsDropDownList(object selectedMeetings = null)
    {
        var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
            .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m, cA = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .SelectMany(z => z.cA.Select(cA => new { m = z.m, cA }))
            .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.ParticipantCityAId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m.m, m.cA, cB = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .SelectMany(w => w.cB.Select(cB => new { m = w.m, cA = w.cA, cB }))
            .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.ParticipantCityBId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m.m, m.cA, m.cB, cC = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .SelectMany(t => t.cC.Select(cC => new { m = t.m, cA = t.cA, cB = t.cB, cC }))
            .Select(
                m =>
                    new
                    {
                        TotalParticipant = m.m.TotalParticipant,
                        MeetingID = m.m.MeetingID,
                        CityID = m.cA.CityID,
                        CityName = m.cA.CityName,
                        MeetingDate = m.m.MeetingStartDate,
                        MeetingName = m.m.MeetingName,
                        NameofMeetingCityIdA = m.cA != null ? m.cA.CityName : null,
                        NameofMeetingCityIdB = m.cB != null ? m.cB.CityName : null,
                        NameofMeetingCityIdC = m.cC != null ? m.cC.CityName : null
                    })
            .OrderBy(x => x.CityName)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(
                i => new
                {
                    Value = i.MeetingID.ToString(),
                    DisplayValue = string.Format("{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})", i.NameofMeetingCityIdA, i.MeetingDate)),

                    Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow,
                    MaksimumCount = i.TotalParticipant,
                    CurrentCount = GetMeetingCount(i.MeetingID)
                }
            ).ToList();

        var selectItems = new List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>(meetingsQuery.Count);
        foreach (var record in meetingsQuery)
        {
            var item = new MyHelpers.MySelectItem
            {
                Text = record.DisplayValue,
                Value = record.Value
            };
            //If Meeting Date is expired or Count for the current record >= Total Participant
            if (record.Expired || record.CurrentCount >= record.MaksimumCount)
            {
                item.Class = "disabled";
                item.Disabled = "disabled";
            }
            selectItems.Add(item);
        }
        ViewBag.MeetingData = selectItems;
    }
```

```
  public int GetMeetingCount(int meetingId)
  {
      return repository.Applicants.Count(x => x.MeetingId == meetingId);
  }
```

The first running of the code I encountered "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." error. But adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" parameter to teh ConnectionString solved this problem and now it works properly.

Comment: @Grundy: I think this is the only way to solve the problem and it is impossible to provide this by using lambda only. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

You need grouping, so use something like this

```
var meetingsQuery = from meeting in repository.Meetings
                    join cityA in repository.Cities on meeting.MeetingCityId equals cityA.CityID into CitiesA
                    join cityB in repository.Cities on meeting.ParticipantCityAId equals cityB.CityID into CitiesB
                    join cityC in repository.Cities on meeting.ParticipantCityBId equals cityC.CityID into citiesC
                    from cityA in citiesA.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from cityB in citiesB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from cityC in citiesC.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby cityA.CityID
                    select new
                        {
                            CityID = cityA.CityID,
                            CityName = cityA.CityName,
                            MeetingDate = meeting.MeetingStartDate,
                            MeetingName = meeting.MeetingName,
                            NameofMeetingCityIdA = cityA != null ? cityA.CityName : null,
                            NameofMeetingCityIdB = cityB != null ? cityB.CityName : null,
                            NameofMeetingCityIdC = cityC != null ? cityC.CityName : null
                        }

var meetings = from meeting in meetingsQuery.AsEnumerable()
               group meeting by new {
                                     meeting.CityID, 
                                     meeting.MeetingDate,
                                     meeting.NameofMeetingCityIdA
                                    } into grouppedMeeting
               select new {
                   Value = grouppedMeeting.Key.CityID.ToString(),
                   DisplayValue = string.Format("{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})", grouppedMeeting.Key.NameofMeetingCityIdA, grouppedMeeting.Key.MeetingDate),
                   Expired = grouppedMeeting.Key.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow,
                   TotalMeetingById= grouppedMeeting.Count()
               }
```

**UPDATE**

in this code

```
    // there is something wrong with the data values
    PopulateDropDownList();
    TempData["message"] = "Please try again.";
    viewModel = new ApplicantViewModel
    {
        Applicant = new Applicant(),
        Applicants = repository.Applicants,
        Lookups = repository.Lookups,
        Cities = repository.Cities
        .ToList()
    };
    return View(viewModel);
```

you don't mark any item as selected, you only add items to viewbag

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help, it was useful (I marked as useful) although using linq instead of lambda. I tested but as there is no where condition on TotalMeetingById= grouppedMeeting.Count() line, I cannot distinguish counts for per city. I tried to use TotalMeetingById = grouppedMeeting.Where(p => p.CityID==6).Count() but unfortunately it did not worked (TotalMeetingById value is 1 although there are 2 records for the related Meeting its CityID=6). Any idea?

Comment: can you provide sample input data, so I could check?

Comment: I added to the last part of the question. Thanks again.

Comment: what output expected for this input?

Comment: I retrieve Dropdownlist values with City and Meeting date with format. In addition to this I can determine Expired parameter according to the Meeting date. I just want to check if the total count for the current meeting (like retrieved for Expired parameter) is equal to a number like 2 in this example.

Comment: @H.Johnson i don't quite understand,now we group by cityId, meeting date and name of meeting, so TotalMeetingById show us count of meetings for this city, date and name. How you want get 2 for this sample if you have one meeting

Comment: I added my updated code above. I needed to use another method in order to solve the problem. Thank you very much for your kind help. I marked useful your replies.